# Issue with React Redux array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I'm having an issue where when I try to update an array in the store by using .push(newvalue). When I push the new value the state is updated from an array to being the value of the length of the array.

State before update: ['asd', 'sdf', 'wer']

State after: 4

action:

```
export function updateLocalCompliments(newCompliment) {
  return ({
    type: LOCAL_COMPLIMENT,
    payload: newCompliment
  })
}
```

reducer: (state.compliments is the actual array)

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  compliments: []
}

function compliments(state=INITIAL_STATE, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case LOCAL_COMPLIMENT:
          return (
            Object.assign({}, state, {
              compliments: state.compliments.push(action.payload)
            })
          )
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `push` does not return the mutated array but its updated length. You will need to handle this differently: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: `push` shouldn't be used with react-redux as it mutates the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the push method modifies the array it is called on and returns the new length. What you want is something like concat().

push: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

concat: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

```
compliments: state.compliments.concat(action.payload)
```

Comment: And here is some branchmark to compare what's the fastest array clone way: https://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/31

Comment: That worked! Thanks for a clear explanation and resources for even more clarification.